# "Etwa" vs "ungefähr". Gibt es einen Unterschied?

Tags: difference, adverb

Ich weiß nicht, ob es einen Unterschied zwischen *etwa* und *ungefähr* gibt und wann man welches Wort benutzt.

Comment: Was haben Deine eigenen Nachforschungen denn ergeben?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

*Etwa* and *ungefähr* are both adverbs. You can use them interchangeably in the sense of *approximately*.

> In etwa/ungefähr drei Stunden
>
> Etwa/Ungefähr fünf Meter hoch
>
> Etwa/Ungefähr zwanzig Personen
>
> Etwa/Ungefähr Bescheid wissen
>
> So in etwa. / So ungefähr.
>
> In etwa. / Ungefähr.

*Ungefähr*, however, is also an adjective. You can't replace this adjective with *etwa*. (But you can still reword the sentence using the adverb and then, again, use both words interchangeably.)

> eine ungefähre Darstellung
>
> eine ungefähre Vorstellung
>
> Google hat zuletzt ebenfalls ungefähre Zahlen zu NSL veröffentlicht <sup>[Zeit Online](http://www.zeit.de/digital/datenschutz/2013-03/microsoft-skype-transparency-report)</sup>

The corresponding adjective to *etwa* would be *etwaig*, which has a different meaning: possibility.

> etwaige[=eventuelle<sup>1</sup>] Verzögerungen (possible delay)
>
> Etwaige private Geschäfte zwischen Louis-Dreyfus und Hoeneß kann der Konzern nicht kommentieren. <sup>[Zeit Online](http://www.zeit.de/wirtschaft/2013-04/adidas-hoeness-louis-dreyfus)</sup>

There are also use cases of *etwa* in which you must not replace it with *ungefähr*; namely, when giving an example.

> Ich etwa[=zum Beispiel] hätte es anders gemacht.
>
> Viele repressive Länder überwachen ihre Bürger, Syrien etwa, der Iran oder Myanmar. <sup>[golem.de](http://www.golem.de/1112/88165.html)</sup>

---

<sup>1</sup>
*eventuell* not equals *eventual*

Comment: You can say both *"so ungefähr"*, and just *"ungefähr"* (similarly *"so in etwa"* - *"in etwa"* this makes *so* almost a filler word).

Comment: Es kommt nicht von ungefähr, dass ungefähr manchmal auch nicht durch etwa ersetzt werden kann.

Comment: @harper Hast du etwa eine Lücke in meiner Antwort ausgemacht?

Comment: @Em1 Nö, keine echte Lücke. Aber "(nicht) von ungefähr" ist noch eine Redewendung. Dabei kann ich aber nicht sagen, ob es dabei ein Adjektiv, Adverb oder sonstwas ist.

Comment: @harper Ein Substantiv und müsste groß geschrieben werden. Der Gebrauch des Substantivs ist jedoch, mit Ausnahme dieser Redewendung, weitesgehend in Vergessenheit geraten. *Ungefähr* bedeutet *Zufall*, *Schicksal*. Daher "Es kommt nicht von Ungefähr" => "Es ist kein Zufall".

Comment: Weitere Synonyme: „circa“ und „rund“.

Answer (score 1):

It's the same, you can use whichever you want.

Both are used often, so it doesn't matter which you choose.

Comment: Sie können noch einen Nachtisch haben, ungefähr einen Pudding.